# does kvm or qemu have out of order execution?

Tags: qemu, kvm

Does kvm have out of order execution feature? if not can we implement to increase virtual machine performance or underlying processor will take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is whether QEMU-KVM emulate OOO, then no they don't. QEMU can emulate an instruction set architecture (so you could run ARM code on x86, for example) but not at the level of instruction re-ordering. And it probably would only add extra overhead to do this in software.

On the other hand, if you run native code inside a VM (x86 binary on x86, but virtualized), then all unprivileged instructions are executed exactly as they would on a bare-metal. So if your CPU can execute out-of-order it will do so also for the code of your VM. The way the privileged processor instructions are executed depends on whether you are using KVM module alongside the QEMU. You can read more about this [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.de/2011/12/kvm-introduction.html) or [in more details here](http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~linn/fachsem0910/hirt/KVM.pdf).

If you think your QEMU is too slow, check whether the KVM module is used: append the command line with by supplying the `-enable-kvm` argument. Also [make sure](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support) your processor has virtualization support.

Also check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/208693/difference-between-kvm-and-qemu)